# FOSElasticaBundle - JMSSerializerBundle exclusion strategies not functioning on FOSUserBundle User entity

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, fosuserbundle, jmsserializerbundle, elastica

I'm using the FOSElasticaBundle with the orm persistence driver and the JMSSerializerBundle serializer.

My users are managed by the FOSUserBundle and I'm trying to index these but exclude some fields such as password.

The JMSSerializerBundle exclusion policies such as @ExclusionPolicy("all") @Expose @Exclude are are not having any affect when added to my User entity, which extends FOS\UserBundle\Model\User. However these strategies work as expected on my other entities.

How do I stop fields such as 'salt' and 'password' from being added to the Elasticsearch index?

Comment: don't you specify the fields to be indexed as part of the elasticsearch configuration ?

Comment: No, mappings defined in the configuration are ignored when using the orm persistence driver (persistence automatic provider). This isn't clearly stated in the documentation but I've read it on GitHub and discovered it in practice for myself.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I'm using the `'query_builder_method'` FOSElasticaBundle configuration setting to call a method that creates a queryBuilder, which uses DQL Partial Object Syntax to only select the fields that I want to be indexed.

Here's some helpful links:

DQL Partial Object Syntax:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax

Use a Custom Doctrine Query Builder:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle#use-a-custom-doctrine-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

This is a know thing with Serializer and annotations. You have to define the exclusion strategy also on the parent (=FOS UserBundle) model.

I have solved it with additional yaml configuration:

This is my config:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            - { path: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/serializer/FOS, namespace_prefix: 'FOS\UserBundle' }
```

And within that folder I have for example a User.Model.yml with this content:

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        email:
            expose: true
```